Uncaught SystemException returned to top level calling integrate in V 14.1
Report to WRI [CASE:5169570]

May be someone with better debugging skills than me in Mathematica internals could figure what causes this. This integral worked OK in V 14.0  but now in V 14.1 it gives
 SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure]

With message in console saying
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].

Clearly this is some kind of regression ( I will report to WRI). BUt may be someone here can figure what causes it or if there is something a user can do to fix it using some option setting?
Does it happen on Linux or the mac? I am using windows 10. I have 128 GB RAM. So memory should not an issue.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
integrand = (a + a*Sec[e + f*x])^m*(d*Sec[e + f*x])^(1/2);
Integrate[integrand, x]

Screen shots


To answer comment about if V 14.0 result was correct or not. I could not verify it. So it looks not correct.
(* V 14 on windows *)
ClearAll["Global`*"];
integrand = (a + a*Sec[e + f*x])^m*(d*Sec[e + f*x])^(1/2)
anti = Integrate[integrand, x];
PossibleZeroQ[RootReduce[Cancel[Together[D[anti,x]-integrand]]]]

(* False *)
Tried few other attempts, but can't verify it.
Update
I found second one
integrand = Cos[e + f*x]^5*(a + b*Sec[e + f*x]^2)^p;
Integrate[integrand, x]

(*SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]*)

But thanks to suggestion below by Carl, changing "IntegrateOptions" now the internal error is gone:


Is the previous result correct? Personally, I'm not inclined to say running out of memory is a bug. It may be a [tag:backslide] (maybe localized to a specific example). It may be the change an enhancement on a hundred other cases. I don't think I could figure that out as an end-user. It's worth reporting, sure, since it may actually be a bug for all I know.

@MichaelE2 V 14.0 result seems not to be correct. I was not able to verify it. I will remove the bugs tag now also until verified. But for me, kernel crash is really a bug, at least from user point of view :)

A kernel crash is a bug, I agree. My kernel did not crash, though (Mac M1). I did not see that mentioned in the question, either.

@MichaelE2  My program stopped when this error happened. It was in middle of loop. I assumed kernel crashed. btw. how does one know for sure if kernel crashed or not? Normally the Evaluation->Start Kernel will show the Local grayed out. Meaning there is no kernel. This tells me the  kernel crashed. This time it was not grayed out. So may be kernel did not crash. But for some reason my program stopped, that is why I thought kernel crashed and had to start everything again. If there is a better way to check if kernel crashed or not, will try it again.

The input line number reset to 1, if the kernel crashes. That's how I know. Also, since I usually set $HistoryLength = 5 when I start the kernel, I can see if $HistoryLength is 5 or infinity. That's how I tell. The reason your loop stopped is that an uncaught Throw[] returns all the way to the top level, effectively aborting the evaluation. When there's an operating system error or "exception" that Mathematica has no control over, like needing too much memory, the user can Catch a SystemException and respond as they see fit....

....You might consider changing your loop to something like Catch[Integrate[ ...], _SystemException, $Failed &] or Catch[Integrate[integrand, x], _SystemException, Failure[#2, <|"value" -> #1|>] &]

You could try increasing the time constraint, e.g. SetSystemOptions[  "IntegrateOptions" -> "IntegrateAlgebraicTimeConstraint" -> 100]

@MichaelE2 Looking at input line counter is much better way to find if kernel crashed or not. Trying this show it did not crash in this case.

The execution takes exceptional long time. This is the case since vs 11 generally, if special complex functions with a tail of conditions on the domains are implied.
Instead of the earlier versions intention do deliver a formal algebraic expression in minimal time, now any internal call of a special function checks for cases of domains or known values in order to yield an exact equation.
As a poisoned gift to the unexperienced user, the new integration packages are buggy, too, stepwise repair left to complaints of users.
Version 6.0
   integrand = (a + a*Sec[e + f*x])^m*(d*Sec[e + f*x])^(1/2);
     Integrate[integrand, x]^2 // FullSimplify

$$\frac{4 d}{f^2}\  \tan ^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} (e+f x)\right) \left(1-\tan ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} (e+f x)\right)\right)^{2 m} (a (\sec (e+f x)+1))^{2 m} F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};m+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\tan ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} (e+f x)\right),-\tan ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} (e+f x)\right)\right){}^2$$
in zero sec.
We have a standard substitution case
 (t^2 -> Tan[y/2]^2,  Cos[y]->(1-t^2)/(1+t^2), 2 dt -> (1+t^2) dy} 

 integrand = (a + a*Sec[e + f*x])^m  (d*Sec[e + f*x])^(1/2) dx

 Assuming[m \[Element] PositiveIntegers && 0 < t < 1, 
  FullSimplify[
        (integrand //. 
           {e + f x -> y,  dx -> dy/f, 
              Sec[y] -> (1 + t^2)/(1 - t^2), 
               dy -> (2 dt)/(1 + t^2)})^2]]

$$-\frac{d  4^{m+1} \left(\frac{a}{t^2-1}\right)^{2 m}}{f^2 \left(t^4-1\right)}  \ \text{dt}^2$$
Rearranging and concentrating to the integral
  \[Integral]1  /( Sqrt[1 + t^2] (1 - t^2)^(m + 1/2)) \[DifferentialD]t //
   FullSimplify

$$t \  F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};m+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};t^2,-t^2\right)  /.  \{t \to \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}(e + f*x)\right\}$$
Caveat: I didn't check anything.

Nice tip! Here's one in return: Integrate[integrand, x, GenerateConditions -> False] cuts out the extra checking. This first time I tried it, it returned with an answer in a second or two. But when I tried again after restarting the kernel, I got the memory allocation failure. Oh well, I thought you gave me a solution.
